# How can I take and email a picture (to the same address every time) in as few clicks as possible?

Tags: camera, share-menu

The best I can achieve so far is to use AutoShare (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dngames.autoshareg). I take the photo, share to autoshare, and it's done. It would be great to be able to snap the picture and have it automatically sent via email, avoiding the share step. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need it to go through email? If you have a recent enough version of Android and Google+, you can enable Instant Upload to automatically sync all the photos and videos you take to Google+, they will initially be set to private but you can of course set to share them with specific people(s) or make them public easily.

There are also some apps that can sync the photos and videos you take to Google Drive or Dropbox or other cloud storage provider. The official Dropbox app provides Camera Upload feature, and I'm sure there are other cloud storage providers that have similar feature either by using their official app or third party app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do need it to email, it's for automatically sending receipts to my company's expense tracking application.